# gremlin / tinkerpop - efficient tree-like traversal result to limit redundancies

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have the following scenario:

[image: graph scenario]

I am trying to produce something like the following resultset:

```
[
  {
    node: A,
    tags: [T1.title, T2.title]
  },
  {
    node: B,
    tags: [T2.title]
  }
]
```

But the best I can do is something that produces me lots of redundant data:

```
[ 
  { node:A, tag: T1.title }, 
  { node:A, tag: T2.title }, 
  { node:B, tag: T2.title } 
]
```

with something like this:

```
g.V()
  .has('label','stuff').as('n')
  .outE('tagged').inV().values('title').as('x')
  .select('n', 'x')
```

I am lost between whether `repeat`, or `cap` or `fold` could help me out

Answer (score 1):

When asking Gremlin questions it is always helpful to provide your sample data as a Gremlin statement that can be copy/pasted into a console session:

```
g.addV('stuff').property('name','a').as('a').
  addV('stuff').property('name','b').as('b').
  addV('tag').property('title','t1').as('t1').
  addV('tag').property('title','t2').as('t2').
  addE('tagged').from('a').to('t1').
  addE('tagged').from('a').to('t2').
  addE('tagged').from('b').to('t2').iterate()
```

You can use `group()` to get a `Map` based format:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('stuff').
......1>   group().
......2>     by('name').
......3>     by(out('tagged').values('title').fold())
==>[a:[t1,t2],b:[t2]]
```

Comment: Nice! Two questions though 
- If I wanted the whole vertex labelled 'stuff' instead of just the name, do I have a chance?
- I thought, to access vertex props I need to go like `outE().inV()` - but you seem to be able to skip that

Comment: if you want the vertex itself then pass an empty `by()` instead of `by('name')` which gets a specific property of the vertext. You can also pass an anonymous traversal to that `by()` if you need something more complex. The point of the first `by()` is to say to Gremlin, "here's what i want the key of the `Map` to be (i.e. what to group on). Note that `outE().inV()` is just `out()`. You only need to do `outE().inV()` if you care about the properties of the edge for some reason (e.g. a filter on edges perhaps).

Comment: This may be specific to the implementation of Cosmos, but leaving by empty takes the key of the Vertex as grouping-Key. I mean, it kind of makes sense, as a complete Vertex probably can't work as a key - so, do you get the complete Vertex in your query as key or also just the id?

Comment: A complete `Vertex` can only be returned as part of the key in GraphSON 3.0. If they only support 2.0 then that might make sense. That said, TinkerPop tends to recommend you not return complete vertices in production code - return only the data that you need (just as you would not specified `SELECT * FROM table` in SQL - you would type out only the fields that you wanted).